# How to properly release Objective-C wrapper class?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Using XCode Instruments to detect leaks I see multiple leaked `TOCImport` objects (48 bytes).
I know that ARC takes care of releasing objects on both the native iOS (Objective C) side and the Delphi side, but the OCwrapper classes are in between.

For example I made this function to simplify creation of UIImageView:

```
function iosUIImageView(aUIImage: UIImage): UIImageView;
begin
  result := TUIImageView.Wrap(TUIImageView.Wrap(TUIImageView.OCClass.alloc).initWithImage(aUIImage));
end;
```

When closing the app, it leaks a `TOCImport` object.

What is the best way to avoid this leak?

Comment: Not sure if that is cause of your problem, but you are calling `TUIImageView.Wrap` twice

Comment: I have posted a bug report on Embarcadero QA: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15097

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it only happens when placed in a function. Calling the same code in place and not through a function does not seem to leak a TOCImport object:

```
LUIIMageView := TUIImageView.Wrap(TUIImageView.Wrap(TUIImageView.OCClass.alloc).initWithImage(aUIImage));
```

I then tried to add `inline` to the function and it also *seems to solve the problem*, at least in some situations. The behavior looks unpredictable to me and I do not know what is going on.